I have a question about Hartshorne Algebraic Geometry Theorem3.4
I have a question about first part of the proof.
Let $\varphi : k[y_1,...,y_n] \rightarrow k[x_0,...,x_n]_{(x_i)}$ be isomorphism by sending $f(y_1,...,y_n)$ to $f(x_0/x_i,...,x_n/x_i)$, leaving out $x_i/x_i$. This isomorphism sends $I(Y_i)$ to $I(Y)S_{(x_i)}$ (this means $I(Y)S_{x_i} \cap S_{(x_i)}$).
I don't understand this sentence. I want to prove $f \in I(Y) \Rightarrow \varphi(f) \in I(Y)S_{xi}$. $(\varphi(f) \in S_{(x_i)}$ is clear)
I want to find $g \in I(Y)$ and $h \in S_{x_i}$ such that $\varphi(f) = gh$.
But I didn't find it.
How can I prove this, or I would like to know other proofs.

Pick $f\in k[x_0,...,x_n]_{(x_i)}$. This means, for some homogenous polynomial $P$,
$$ f = \frac{P(x_0,...,x_n)}{x_i^n} $$
In Hartshorne, $S_{(x_i)}$ does not mean "localization at $x_i$", it rather means "degree zero localization", therefore, $\deg(P) = n$ and $P$ is a homogenous polynomial (by definition). This means you can split $x_i$ into a product $x_i^ax_i^bx_i^c...$ in such a way so that each exponent matches with each monomial.
It is simplest to illustrate this in an example, say that,
$$ f = \frac{x_0^3 + x_1^2x_2 + x_0x_1x_2}{x_1^3} $$
Then we can write,
$$ f = \left( \frac{x_0}{x_1} \right)^3 + \left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right) + \left(\frac{x_0}{x_1}\right)\left( \frac{x_2}{x_1} \right) $$
Then the polynomial $y_0^3 + y_2^1 + y_0y_2$ will be the inverse polynomial under that map.

Sorry I still don't understand my question. I understood how to generate inverse polynomial, but why I(Y) is sent to I(Y)S_(xi).
